# Use realm in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, realm

Is it possible to use Realm.io in an ionic app? I have seen, that there is a JavaScript version, but I can only find React examples.
'
So is it possible (and solid) to use realm in an ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

The Crowd is asking, but there´s no support (yet).

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/261